# Should you dispose the Entity Framework object in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am developing an MVC3 application and have been wondering about the following. Should the Entity Framework object (`DbContext` object) be disposed before passing data to the view?

The obvious issue with this is you will not be able to drill down into the foreign key relations.

Is there a performance hit by doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you absolutely should dispose of the context 
The performance hit should be minimal . Any object that can be disposed of should be disposed of ALWAYS.
Dependency injection can free you from having to worry about calling it if done properly as the DI framework will dispose of it for you if instructed.

Comment: But then how are you supposed to access the related objects from your result set.

Comment: +1 Also, since controllers implement IDisposable, you can store the context in the controller and then override `Dispose(bool)` to dispose it. The view then gets full use of Code First's lazy loading if you *truly* need it.

Comment: you can, thats how the scaffolding templates work for entity framework, but I don't like stuffing contexts into controllers. I'd much rather have these injected and managed for me : )

Comment: @aspect how do you mean include, as in db.Customers.Where(o=>o.CustomerId==id).Include(o=>o.Orders)  ?  thats a different question, but easy nonetheless. Your info should be loaded in the controller. ALL of it which means lazy loading should be off (in the sense you won't access it after your controller). Ideally you want to use a ViewModel here that contains all the data you want to package up and send to the view rather than using your EF objects direct. See http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass EF entities into your view, use the view model pattern. And don't rely too much on lazy loading, it will perform poorly. Use the Include method to eagerly load the objects you need.

And yes, you need dispose (or preferably using), otherwise your system will leak connections and probably starve the pool under non-trivial loads.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with the answer of Adam Tuliper. With the addition, that if you need to access the related objects you could use the .Include(o => o.EntityName) method to make sure the data is included in the data retrieval.

This blog is writing about loading related objects:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx

Comment: stay away from magic strings. You can use .Include(o=>o.EntityName) which checks upon compile.

Answer (score 1):

If, by "entityframe work object" you mean the DbContext object, then No, don't worry about it.

...also, this should be a Controller level object, not a View level one.

Comment: True (also, this should be a Controller level object, not a View level one), but I was passing the result of a query into the view to be used

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense.  It helps having the full story. :)

Comment: Anyway, your DbContext should still be in the Controller's scope.  Your code should be acting upon that, probably with a Linq query, to pull out the data you need in your view.

Comment: My dbcontext is within the scope of the controller

Comment: Then for the love of God, don't dispose it in an Action method.

Comment: dbcontext should _always_ be disposed.

Comment: Allow me to clearify, anything IDisposable should be disposed, but don't dispose a class level object in an instance method, that's bad practice.  So likewise, don't dispose a Controller-scoped object inside of an Action method, which is what the OP asked "Should the [DbContext object] be disposed before passing data to the view?" The answer is No.  To dispose it, override the Controller's Dispose method, and do it there.

Comment: Your last comment is much better than your answer :)